# Automapper - from object with IEnumerable<A> property to IEnumerable<B>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

this mapping
`_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>(response);`
where response is of type `GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse`

gives me this error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'GetEnumerator' in type 'Proxy_System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[StoreManager.Web.Areas.Turnazione.Models.SchedulerEventViewModel, StoreManager.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]_48512780_' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' does not have an implementation.
```

mapping directly the property `events` it works:
`_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>(response.events);`

So, how should it be the mapping configuraraon in order to map simply the entire object(as i thought it would work) and not specifing the IEnumerable property during the mapping
`_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>(response);`

these are the classes:

```
public class GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse
{
    public IEnumerable<SchedulerEventCommandModel> events { get; set; }
}

public class SchedulerEventCommandModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceID { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
        public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int dipendenteId { get; set; }
        public int idReparto { get; set; }
        public int idPuntoVendita { get; set; }
        public string stato { get; set; }
    }


public class SchedulerEventViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        private DateTime start;
        public DateTime Start
        {
            get
            {
                return start;
            }
            set
            {
                start = value.ToUniversalTime();
            }
        }


        private DateTime end;
        public DateTime End
        {
            get
            {
                return end;
            }
            set
            {
                end = value.ToUniversalTime();
            }
        }

        public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceID { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
        public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }


        //custom fiels
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int dipendenteId { get; set; }
        public int idReparto { get; set; }
        public int idPuntoVendita { get; set; }
        public string stato { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the mapping definition:

```
CreateMap<SchedulerEventViewModel, SchedulerEventCommandModel>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse, IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>().ReverseMap()
                .ForMember(o => o.events, b => b.MapFrom(x => x));
//i tried to be more explicit as well
//CreateMap<GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse, IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>().ReverseMap()
//                .ForMember(o => o.events, b => b.MapFrom(x => x.AsEnumerable()));
//CreateMap<GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse, IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>().ReverseMap()
//                .ForMember(o => o.events, b => b.MapFrom(x => x.AsEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>()));
```

Comment: You need `ConvertUsing` in the `IEnumerable` map.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Custom Type Resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) via `ConvertUsing` as mentioned by @Lucian.

While using `ConvertUsing`, it doesn't support `ReverseMap` method. Thus you have to define the mapping rules separately.

1. Map from `GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse` to `IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>`.
2. Map from `IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>` to `GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse`.

```cs
CreateMap<GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse, IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dest, context) => context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>>(src.events));
                                                                                                                                           
CreateMap<IEnumerable<SchedulerEventViewModel>, GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dest, context) => 
    {
        dest = new GetWorkShiftCurrentCachedResponse();
        dest.events = context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SchedulerEventCommandModel>>(src);
                                                                                        
        return dest;
    });
```

Comment: You don't need `ConverUsing` for the second map, you can use `ForMember`. Somewhat terser I'd say.